Use VBA to calculate the relative X,Y of the centre of the bottom of a 3D shape
I am working with 3D shapes in Excel / PowerPoint and I need to calculate a particular co-ordinate. I am using Excel to handle the manipulation, the content is in PowerPoint.
Say I have this shape sitting on my slide. Lets say it is at 100pt X "left" and 50pt Y "top".
The model's 2D width is 300px and the height is 215pt.

The X, Y point I want to determine is the centre of the bottom face of the 3D cuboid that contains the shape.
Here's a rough diagram of what I mean ...

I can get at the .Model3D object and/or the .ThreeD objects of the shape but I can't figure out if the information I'd need to calc the position is available.
Any thoughts on whether this is possible?
Needs to be something I can calc for any given 3D Model as I have lots to process.
If I were doing it manually then I would just draw a line from my anchor point (100,50) through to where the dotted lines cross and I'd be able to work out the new point's X and Y but I need code to do it, plus I don't think there is a way to accurately reproduce the 3D model's cuboid (my drawing is just a guess).
Thanks for any help anyone can give.

OK, have worked on it more, with contributions below - thanks to those people. I have got a workable approach that gets the bottom of the cuboid reasonably well. Need to take it into my main project to test how well it works but hopefully it is close enough.
Dim sld             As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shp             As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim vShpTgt         As Variant

Dim dbLeft          As Double
Dim dbTop           As Double

Dim dbWidth         As Double
Dim dbHeight        As Double
Dim dbDepth         As Double

Dim dbAngleX        As Double
Dim dbAngleY        As Double
Dim dbAngleZ        As Double
Dim dbOpp           As Double
Dim dbAdj           As Double
Dim dbHyp           As Double

Dim dbOffsetBackY   As Double
Dim dbOffsetBackH   As Double
Dim dbOffsetFrontY  As Double

Dim dbOffsetSpotX   As Double
Dim dbOffsetSpotY   As Double

Dim iShp            As Integer

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

'Drop any test shapes
For iShp = sld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Left(sld.Shapes(iShp).Name, 7) = "shpTemp" Then
        sld.Shapes(iShp).Delete
    End If
Next

'To get at .Model3D Shape needs to be a Variant (or always referred to in full)
Set vShpTgt = sld.Shapes("modTarget")
dbLeft = vShpTgt.Left
dbTop = vShpTgt.Top

'I have three shapes
' 1) the Target one I am trying to make a calc on
' 2) same shape/model set to a view of Front
' 3) Same shape/model set to a view of Above

'These are the Width, Height and Depth of the imaginary Cuboid
dbWidth = sld.Shapes("modFront").Width 'not used in the end - left-to-right middle was good enough
dbHeight = sld.Shapes("modFront").Height
dbDepth = sld.Shapes("modAbove").Height

'The rotations in play for the shape
dbAngleX = vShpTgt.Model3D.rotationX
dbAngleY = vShpTgt.Model3D.rotationY 'not used in the end - left-to-right middle was good enough
dbAngleZ = vShpTgt.Model3D.RotationZ 'not used in the end - left-to-right middle was good enough

'Calculate where the back of the cuboid has moved to on the Y plane
'It is a fraction of the box's height taking in account the
dbOffsetBackY = -1 * (dbHeight - (Sin(Deg2Rad(90 - dbAngleX)) * dbHeight))

'The new height of the back of the box (s seen on a 2D plane) is the height minus
'the Y shift of the back now it is tilted
dbOffsetBackH = dbHeight + dbOffsetBackY

'The drop (as seen on a 2D plane) of the front top edge of the cuboid based on Rotation X
dbOffsetFrontY = Sin(Deg2Rad(dbAngleX)) * dbDepth

'In the end, the middle of the Target shapes overall Width seems to work well enough
'In theory I should do similar calcs to above to work out where the box is sitting
'but this is close enough for my purposes.
dbOffsetSpotX = dbLeft + (vShpTgt.Width / 2)

'Top position plus half the Y shift for the spot is drop in the front edge,
'offset (upwards) by the backwards shift of the back of the box
dbOffsetSpotY = dbTop + dbOffsetBackH + (dbOffsetFrontY / 2)

'Draw a small circle wher the perceived base-centre is
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, dbOffsetSpotX - 5, dbOffsetSpotY - 5, 10, 10)
shp.Name = "shpTempSpot"
shp.Fill.Solid
shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 0)
shp.Line.Visible = False
shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
Set shp = Nothing

Set vShpTgt = Nothing
Set sld = Nothing

This is a rough diagram of that the calcs are getting as far as the Y shift goes.

This is some examples showing the centre spot as a small yellow dot.

The dot seems a bit low on the bottom left example but will see how it looks once implemented the calc into my project. The bigger aim is about positioning things based on their centre points so they align nicely.

Will you only be calculating coordinates using cuboid shapes or other simple/complex shapes?

Hi Peter. Sorry missed this comment . Complex 3D Models but I figure they are always "contained" in a cuboid even if you can't really see it. The one I have drawn around the car is just what I suppose it would look like.

Width, Height and Depth should be Single rather that Double.

is the orientation consistent? If so, we can try:
Sub test()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim topLeftX As Single, topLeftY As Single
    Dim width2D As Single, height2D As Single
    Dim depth As Single
    Dim centerX As Single, centerY As Single

    'Change to your slide and shape
    Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) ' Change to your slide index
    Set shp = slide.Shapes(1) ' Change to your shape index

    'Extract properties
    topLeftX = shp.Left
    topLeftY = shp.Top
    width2D = shp.Width
    height2D = shp.Height

    ' Extract depth (3D property)
    If shp.ThreeD.Visible Then
        depth = shp.ThreeD.Depth
    Else
        depth = 0 ' Default to zero if no depth
    End If

    ' Calculate an approximation of bottom face's center
    centerX = topLeftX + (width2D / 2)
    centerY = topLeftY + height2D

    ' Output results
    Debug.Print "Center of Bottom Face: (" & centerX & ", " & centerY & ")"
    ' If you need this for many objects, you can use a loop, use this as a call or change it to a function
End Sub


Hi. No the orientations are not that consistent but the above gives me something to work on and I can see how it pans out. Will have an explore now. Thanks

Hmm, it seems that Threed.Depth is always 36 and not related to the 3D Model. Think it might be for when you tell a 2D shape to look 3D and it develops bevels etc. Not sure I can find a proper Z (depth) parameter

A) I'd suggest checking all attributes of an object that is 3D
B) If all depths are the same, try checking ".ThreeD.RotationX" and ".ThreeD.RotationY" and we could try a simple trigonometry solution
C) Should all depths be the same? Are all images with the same height and width?
if so, than it would make sense if all images have similar orientations

Hi rhashiba. Yes, thanks for that, have reached that conclusion as well. Have to use Rot X, Y and Z to figure out which way my (imaginary) cuboid that contains my model is going. Then I should be able to determine the spot I need. Will share it back here if I can figure it out!

To answer your other questions - no, not all same height and/or width. There is a pattern to the orientations but there are a lot of them.

Another approach using trigonometry
Sub test()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim topLeftX As Single, topLeftY As Single
    Dim width2D As Single, height2D As Single, depth As Single
    Dim rotationX As Single, rotationY As Single
    Dim centerX As Single, centerY As Single

    'Change to your slide and shape
    Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) ' Change to your slide index
    Set shp = slide.Shapes(1) ' Change to your shape index

    ' Extract properties
    topLeftX = shp.Left
    topLeftY = shp.Top
    width2D = shp.Width
    height2D = shp.Height
    
    ' Extract properties
    If shp.ThreeD.Visible Then
        depth = shp.ThreeD.Depth
        rotationX = shp.ThreeD.RotationX
        rotationY = shp.ThreeD.RotationY
    Else
        depth = 0
        rotationX = 0
        rotationY = 0
    End If

    ' Calculate center of the bottom face without rotation
    Dim unrotatedCenterX As Single, unrotatedCenterY As Single, unrotatedCenterZ As Single
    unrotatedCenterX = topLeftX + (width2D / 2)
    unrotatedCenterY = topLeftY + height2D
    unrotatedCenterZ = depth / 2

    ' Adjust based on 3D rotation (RotationX and RotationY in degrees)
    Dim radiansX As Double, radiansY As Double
    radiansX = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(rotationX)
    radiansY = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(rotationY)
    
    Dim rotatedCenterX As Double, rotatedCenterY As Double
    rotatedCenterX = unrotatedCenterX + (unrotatedCenterZ * Sin(radiansY))
    rotatedCenterY = unrotatedCenterY - (unrotatedCenterZ * Sin(radiansX))

    Debug.Print "Center of Bottom Face: (" & rotatedCenterX & ", " & rotatedCenterY & ")"
    ' If you need this for many objects, you can use a loop, use this as a call or change it to a function
End Sub


Hi. I see what you are going for but it isn't working for me. The "depth" of the ThreeD object is lways 36. There doesn't seem to be a way of getting the true depth of the image. Also Rot X, Y and Z in the ThreeD object are 0 for a 3D Model. Can get the rotations but have to used .Model3D and for that to work against a Shape object the object has to be defined as a variant. No idea why. I'll  keep exploring based on Trig but starting to think a critical figure is missing and not sure it can be found or worked out.

Thanks for persisting with this though!
